# how to eject a DVD from a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, hardware, dvd, grub

On an older Macbook from 2008 the DVD is stuck in the tray.  Unfortunately, GRUB isn't booting properly so there's no OS.

How can I eject the disk?  It's a slot loaded disk, so no button or tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, there's an eject button:

[image]

I held that down at boot.  Still get the grub error, but at least the DVD's ejected.

Comment: For the benefit of others, another option is to hold down your mouse button (or Trackpad as the case may be) as you boot up your Mac. This should eject any optical media (CD, DVD) you have stuck in your optical drive.